# Error when Parsing a JSONified Array

Tags: json, gson

I have a JSON string that contains an array of SpellingError objects.
I use Gson to convert this to a list of SpellingErrors.
The parsing works fine ( Or at least ddoes not throw any parsinig errors).  However when I try to iterate through what I hoped would be a list of SpellingErrors I find that they are in fact StringMaps,  and I get the error 
"com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to SpellingError"

Any idea what is the correct way to use Gson to pull my Array of objects out of the JSON string?  I can see there are 3 StringMap objects in the array that represent my 3 objects.

Here is the offending code

```
    spellingErrorsJSON = "[{\"context\":\"This is a stmple string\",\"errorIndex\":\"3\"},{\"context\":\"This is a stmple string 2\",\"errorIndex\":\"3\"},{\"context\":\"This is a stmple string 3\",\"errorIndex\":\"3\"}]";
    List<SpellingError>spellingErrors;  
    spellingErrors = m_gson.fromJson( spellingErrorsJSON, List.class );

    for( SpellingError spellingError : spellingErrors )
    {
        if( spellingError.isValid() )
        {
            String spellingMistake = spellingError.getSpellingMistake();
            String[] suggestions = Query.lookupSpelling( spellingMistake, LOCALE_US);
        }
    }
```

If however I use

```
m_gson.fromJson( spellingErrorsJSON, SpellingError[].class );
```

instead then I get a parsing exception 
"Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY”

Here is my SpellingError PoJo

```
public class SpellingError
{
    private String [] context;
    private int errorIndex;

    public String[] getContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(String[] context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getErrorIndex()
    {
        return errorIndex;
    }

    public void setErrorIndex(int index)
    {
        this.errorIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TypeToken to tell Gson, which type of objects you want to have in your resulting list. 
Replace your line

```
spellingErrors = m_gson.fromJson( spellingErrorsJSON, List.class );
```

with

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<SpellingError>>(){}.getType();
spellingErrors = m_gson.fromJson( spellingErrorsJSON, collectionType );
```

EDIT: This is working for me:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

class SpellingError
{
    private String  context;
    private int errorIndex;

    public String getContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(String context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getErrorIndex()
    {
        return errorIndex;
    }

    public void setErrorIndex(int index)
    {
        this.errorIndex = index;
    }
}


public class TestGson {
    private static Gson m_gson = new Gson();

    class DataPacket {
        public String fn;
        public Object data;
    }

    class ChatPacket {
        public int roomId;
        public String message;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String spellingErrorsJSON = "[{\"context\":\"This is a stmple string\",\"errorIndex\":\"3\"},{\"context\":\"This is a stmple string 2\",\"errorIndex\":\"3\"},{\"context\":\"This is a stmple string 3\",\"errorIndex\":\"3\"}]";
        List<SpellingError>spellingErrors;  
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<SpellingError>>(){}.getType();
        spellingErrors = m_gson.fromJson( spellingErrorsJSON, collectionType );


        for( SpellingError spellingError : spellingErrors )
        {
            String spellingMistake = spellingError.getContext();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: No,  didn't work,  getting the second error I listed above ... "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING" :(

Comment: Please see my edited answer above - I included a complete test class that is working for me.